# Cannot display Home page in MVC 4 Application having ACS Configured for authentication?

Tags: azure, acs

I have developed MVC4 application, in which i have home page. On home page, i have embedded ACS Login page for Authentication. When i run the web role, it directly loads the default ACS login page and not application home page.
I have designed home page on Index.cshtml under Home controller.
I Have added Realm as `http://127.0.0.1:81/Home/`

If you have come across similar situation, please help.

Comment: If you're getting automatically redirected to the default ACS login page, it's because you have the `passiveRedirectEnabled` attribute set to true in your web.config.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry that I have to use reference links, but the answer is not just "simply do that", and requires deeper understanding of security protocols.

Use this as a starting point: [Creating Custom Login Page for Federated Authentication using Azure ACS](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/development/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-federated-authentication-with-windows-azure-acs/) to understand the besics.

Then you may take a look at the [ACS Code Samples on MSDN](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-AD-Access-0dcde385). They contain a perfectly suitable for you [MVC3CustomSignInPage](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-AD-Access-0dcde385/sourcecode?fileId=71587&pathId=676687348) sample app.

Answer (score 1):

Your home page controller is tagged with attribute [Authorize], or web.config have a section like

```
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
</authorization>
```

Remove attribute and/or change web.config section to

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: no. The user has `enablepassiveredirect=true` in their `system.identityModel.Services` configuration! Please pay attention to the details in the question.

Comment: Please point me where is an information about enablepassiveredirect=true in question?

Comment: browse the [ACS Code Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazure/Windows-Azure-AD-Access-0dcde385) it is in every single one of them. Sometimes it is `true` sometimes it is `false`. As already said, pay attention to question details and tags!

Comment: Why not use Danila's solution? The web config setting he is suggesting be changes is denying access to anonymous users, which is obviously the problem. Changing it to allow all users resolves the issue.